# Whats the meaning of "unique up to isomorphism"?

Tags: math, algebra

Whats the meaning of "unique up to isomorphism"? To give some context, I came across the phrase [reading about initial algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_algebra#Use_in_computer_science).

It seems that *up to* means "to ignore" (sometimes said as "modulo"). Isomorphism means that the objects are the same in some way (with a bidirectional mapping). However, "unique ignoring that they are the same" still perplexes me.

Comment: It seems like you might get a better answer on  http://math.stackexchange.com or possibly http://cs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I thought about posting at http://mathoverflow.net and http://cs.stackexchanges.com but there was a warning about asking a "research" oriented question (or something like that) which put me off :).

Comment: @StevenShaw: math.stackexchange.com, not mathoverflow.net! The latter is indeed for professional mathematicians; the former is not.  BTW, "unique up to unique isomorphism" is often a more valuable property than simply "unique up to isomorphism".

Comment: @MarkDickinson, I may then ask on math.stackexchange.com but I'm concerned that I won't understand the answer given [this similar question there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473420/what-is-the-difference-between-being-unique-unique-up-to-isomorphism-and-unique).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about initial algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: No worries, I moved the question over to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776101/whats-the-meaning-of-unique-up-to-isomorphism

Answer (score 3):

Rather than "unique ignoring they are the same" it is more like "unique (ignoring irrelevant differences that are no real differences in the context that we are discussing here)".

For example, if you are considering geometic figures, an equilateral triangle is "the same" as another equilateral triangle of twice the size that is upside-down, so you can count this as a unique figure.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I have a set of numbers {0, 1, 2, ..., 11} under addition modulo 12 or a regular 12-gon under the rotations generated by a rotation of 30 degrees. Both of these sets are different, but the corresponding algebraic structure is the same (it's the cyclic group on 12 elements). There's an isomorphism between them in that addition by "1" modulo 12 corresponds to rotation (say clockwise) by 30 degrees.

Its awkward to say "look at this unique structure" because it's clearly shown up in at least two distinct settings. But somehow the distinguishing features between these two examples are non-essential in that they disappear under isomorphism while the algebraic structure is preserved. Hence they concede "It's unique, *up to ismorphism*."

Answer (score 2):

The background notion is that of equivalence relations. An equivalence relation on a set is a relation, ~, on a set S which shares with equality the three properties of symmetry (`x ~ y => y ~ x`) reflexivity (`x ~ x` for all `x`) and transitivity (`x ~ y ~ z => x ~ z`). They are ubiquitous, and familiar, in mathematics. For example 1/2 is equivalent to 5/10 even though 1/2 is manifestly not really identical to 5/10. Whenever you have an equivalence relation you can have objects which are the same in one perspective but different from another. For example, it is a common undergraduate programming exercise to implement sets as lists. As a set you wouldn't distinguish between the set `{1,2,3}` and the set `{2,3,1}`, but if you represent them as lists, you *can* distinguish `[1,2,3]` from `[2,3,1]`. These later are different qua lists but the same qua sets.

Isomorphism is an equivalence relation on algebraic structures. To say that initial algebras are unique up to isomorphism *means* that they are all equivalent to each other with respect to the equivalence relation of isomorphism. @AlfredRossi 's example is an excellent illustration of the way this plays out in abstract algebra.

Comment: _"Isomorphism is an equivalence relation on algebraic structures. To say that initial algebras are unique up to isomorphism means that they are all equivalent to each other with respect to the equivalence relation of isomorphism."_ 
Very well put. It's a shame that not enough of our mathematical education (and texts) anymore is expressed in terms of a _relation_, when it's often a very valuable way of defining and understanding the connection between algebraic structures.